# About layout performance - HierarchyViewer

Tags: android, performance, layout, hierarchy

I want to ask about hierarchy view result. I have an custom component i paste the layout code below, i dont understand what is the problem ? Why hierarchy viewer gives red point  ?

Any opinion will be appreciated

**hierarchy view result**

Measure : 1.873 ms
Layout: 0.298 ms
Draw : 1.472 ms

yellow / red / yellow

**Custom componenet Layout**

```
    <com.ab.framework.component.ui.RelativeLayout1
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <com.ab.framework.component.ui.TextView1
            android:id="@+id/textMoneyRight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/moneyview_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/moneyview_TextField2_Padding"
            android:text="@string/empty_text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/moneyview_textField2_size" />

        <com.ab.framework.component.ui.TextView1
            android:id="@+id/textMoneyLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/moneyview_item_margin3x"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textMoneyRight"
            android:text="@string/empty_text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/moneyview_textField1_size"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <com.ab.framework.component.ui.TextView1
            android:id="@+id/textMoneySeperator"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textMoneyRight"
            android:text="@string/price_seperator"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <com.ab.framework.component.ui.TextView1
            android:id="@+id/textMoneyCurrency"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textMoneyRight"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/moneyview_item_margin"
            android:text="@string/currency" />

        <com.ab.framework.component.ui.TextView1
            android:id="@+id/textMoneyDescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textMoneyCurrency"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/moneyview_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/moneyview_TextField2_Padding"
            android:text="@string/empty_text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/moneyview_textField2_size" />
    </com.ab.framework.component.ui.RelativeLayout1>

</merge>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Red / yellow / green points are relative values. You should be looking at them only when you notice there is a problem with performance.

Try with a simple layout containing `TextView` and `ImageView` and you should see red dot there too.